# Get the type of a variable in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

If I define a variable like `set @a = "1";`. How can I see that @a is a string?

Comment: Since variables have to declared up front with a specific type, you should already know that @a is a string. But obviously there is more going on here. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I don't get your approach here. I don't think you can get a variable type in mysql, but I might be wrong

Comment: This is mostly for debugging purposes. There's a stored proc setting an out variable and I just want to ensure everything is being set accordingly. You're right though, the SP declares the data type up front. I guess I was confused by the ability to just say @this = "that" without specifying a type in the CLI client.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - I think there may be some confusion here.  MySQL allows for variables to be set without an explicit type so there's no requirement to define the type up front. This is unlike TSQL where you declare variable stating the type. Maybe you assumed this was a TSQL question?

Comment: @marcgg, I think you "get" what he means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot determine the type of a variable in MySQL.

As an alternative, you can easily `CAST()` your variable in the type you desire:

```
@a = CAST(123 AS CHAR);
```

More information and examples about casting in the MySQL Manual:

> [11.9. Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: You CAN determine the type of a variable in MySQL. See my answer below.

Answer (score 39):

You CAN determine the type of a variable in MySQL. Create a table by selecting your variable and then check the column type:

```
set @a:="1"; -- your variable

drop temporary table if exists foo;
create temporary table foo select @a; -- dirty magic
desc foo;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| @a    | longtext | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: _Doesn't seem?_ Could you please be more specific? `Type` column would reflect variable type as it is represented by MySQL **internally**. It doesn't have to be minimal/optimal. For instance, `longtext` won't magically become `varchar(1)` or `tinyint(1)` as in my example above.

Comment: This seems bugged as mentioned on [another thread](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57363/9405) ............... Are you sure that the returned type in the temporary table is the **same type** as the one in the variable? Seems like some kind of implicit conversion is done when you did `create table foo select @a`........ Why does it return `longlong` for simple integers and `longblob` for simple bit fields?

Comment: this is the best  answer on internet

Answer (score 1):

In MySql, you cannot identify the Datatype of the variable. But there is a way to identify only the strings and Integer by using [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html) :

```
set @a = "11";
SELECT CAST(@a AS SIGNED); // Output : 11

set @a = "text";
SELECT CAST(@a AS SIGNED); // Output : 0


set @a = "121212";
SELECT CAST(@a AS SIGNED); // Output : 121212

set @a = "Mysql is open source";
SELECT CAST(@a AS SIGNED); // Output : 0
```