# How not to display nothing, if one of the table contains a word or string in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

it's my first time here.
So as the title suggest, I have this code that will add, calculate, display all the grades of the students as General Average

I was trying to NOT display the General Average of the grades if one of the columns contain a string, Example "D" or dropped. But i don't have an idea how.

```
SELECT ( 
        SELECT ROUND(AVG(grades_avg)) 
        FROM grades 
        WHERE studentid = 20160001
        AND grades.schoolyearseq_id = 20162017 
        AND grades.semseq_id = 201620171 
        ) AS average");
```

so any help would very much appreciated. thank you

---

Update 1

Hi guys, sorry took me long to update..
i try to implement the answers/comments that you guys put sadly, 
the query would still output a number.
the query above would compute the 'D' or dropped as '0' or zero.
the query below would compute but will ignore the 'D'
i also attached the image below[image: grades sample]

will try to update you guys once i cracked this thing. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a WHERE?

```
WHERE grades.grades_avg NOT IN ('D', 'dropped')
```

So it would look like:

```
SELECT (SELECT ROUND(AVG(grades_avg)) 
FROM grades 
WHERE studentid = 20160001
AND grades_avg NOT IN ('D', 'dropped')
AND grades.schoolyearseq_id = 20162017 
AND grades.semseq_id = 201620171 
    ) AS average");
```

Comment: This will still display the average of the grades of a student if they have any grades other than 'D' or 'dropped'

Comment: hi, thank you.sadly it would still output a grade. query would still compute and display an answer. but will try to solve and update this post

Answer (score 0):

Try CASE statement like below:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN grades_avg = 'D' OR grades_avg = 'dropped' THEN ' '
    ELSE ROUND(AVG(grades_avg))
END AVERAGE
FROM grades
WHERE studentid = 20160001
AND grades.schoolyearseq_id = 20162017
AND grades.semseq_id = 201620171;
```

Comment: hi, thank you.sadly it would still output a grade. query would still compute and display an answer. but will try to solve and update this post

Answer (score 0):

I think we can check the type of `grades_avg` if it can be converted to int -> `AVG()` it else ...
I found the way check data of columns is `int` or not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49133032/8949672

Btw, this is my demo implements.

```
SELECT (
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(grades_avg AS SIGNED) <> 0 THEN
            ROUND(AVG(grades_avg))
        ELSE ''
    END     
) AS average
FROM grades 
WHERE studentid = 20160001
    AND grades.schoolyearseq_id = 20162017 
    AND grades.semseq_id = 201620171
```

--- Updated

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144748/8949672

```
SELECT (
    SELECT ROUND(AVG(grades_avg)) 
    FROM grades 
    WHERE studentid = 20160001
        AND CAST(grades_avg AS SIGNED) <> 0
        AND grades.schoolyearseq_id = 20162017 
        AND grades.semseq_id = 201620171 
) AS average");
```

I hope it works.

Comment: hi, thank you.sadly it would still output a grade. query would still compute and display an answer. but will try to solve and update this post